# Finding the bound of a sequence sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am dealing with a sum of this form:
$S = l *[b^{-1}*a_1 + b^{-2}*a_1*a_2 + b^{-3}*a_1*a_2*a_3...+b^{-n}*a_1*a_2...*a_n]$, where $l$ is some positive constant, $b$ is a constant $>1$, and the sum of terms $a_1+a_2+a_3...+a_n = C$, where C is some constant $>n$. I initially was wondering if $S$ is maximized when $a_1=a_2=a_3...=a_n$, however this appears not to be the case. Is there a general way to calculate the upper bound of $S$ in terms of constants, or to identify the values of $a_1, a_2...$ such that $S$ is maximized?

Comment: Here's a possible start: Take $a'_i=a_i/b$, then you basically want to maximize $a'_1+a'_1a'_2+\ldots+a'_1a'_2\ldots a'_n$ subject to $a'_1+\ldots+a'_n=C/b$, a (positive) constant. Perhaps study the cases $n=2,n=3$ to see if your conjecture holds?

Comment: Thanks, I see that my original assumption was wrong. Is there any way to calculate a bound for this?

Answer (score 1):

Take the simple case of maximizing $J = a_0 + a_0 a_1$ subject to $a_0 + a_1 = A$. The constraint tells us
$a_1 = A - a_0$ so $J = a_0 + a_0(A - a_0) = (A + 1)a_0 - a_0^2$, which has an extremum at $a_0 = (A + 1)/2$, $a_1 = (A - 1)/2$, its value there $(A + 1)^2/4$. Might help a bit, and it does give you a counterexample.

Thanks to @Mindlack for pointing an algebra misstep of mine, now fixed.

Comment: Wait... $J=a_0(A+1-a_0)=\frac{A+1}{2}\frac{A+1}{2}=\frac{(A+1)^2}{4}$, no?

Comment: You're correct @Mindlack, thanks, I'll fix my answer.